# Eco-driving betweeen Phoenix and Austin through Albuquerque

Tags: usa, driving, texas, arizona, new-mexico

I've found out that my car is capable of doing about 2× of the city mpg if driven on highways at 50—60mph in place of 70—80mph (going 80mph appears to retain the city-spec'ed mpg in my 2.5L Jetta).

Travelling between some areas of the US is rather straightforward in that there is only a single Interstate to take, which usually provides the best (and sometimes only) route; however, what's the best approach if I'm travelling between something like Phoenix and Austin, through Albuquerque, where neither Phoenix nor Austin are directly connected with any West-East Interstates?

I've noticed that Google Maps has an option of avoiding highways, however, it's not very clear whether or not that's something that I want.  My car is still a normal passenger car, so, I'd still prefer going through roads with quality pavement, just not at 80+mph, so, the best route may not be the most straightforward one that's designed for passing at 80mph.

Comment: Interstates have the advantage that they're always at least two lanes in each direction, so even if you drive slow, faster traffic can pass you.  Other routes, e.g. US 60, are often just one lane in each direction.  So even if the speed limit is a bit lower, you'll actually be obstructing traffic that wants to drive that fast - which may invite unsafe passing or road rage.  Or you'll have to pull over frequently, which will surely not help your mileage.

Comment: Safety trumps economy in my opinion - you'll be best to take Interstates and drive a few mph below the speed limit if you like (lower, of course, in poor conditions).  70 mph in an 80 zone wouldn't be too horrid.  Whatever you do, ensure you stay in the driving lane (right), not passing lane, and let faster traffic pass you.  And be sure to adjust your speed as needed to accommodate merging traffic.  If you really insist on much slower speeds, drive in poorer weather where that's a safe and prudent speed.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie, yes, of course; coming from someone who used to drive 80+, I'm obviously going to take reasonable care to ensure not to intentionally (or by omission) obstruct my prior selves. :-)  Plus, even though the roads are designed for 80+, they're still usually posted at just 70mph or 75, which I'll likely cruise at 15 under, in the left lane.

Comment: @cnst I hope the "in the left lane" was a typo :) If you were serious, that's highly dangerous.  Stick to the right lane, always, unless passing slower traffic.

Comment: There's really not much unsafe about going, say, 55mph in a 70mph zone, as long as you stay in the right lane. This is evidenced by the fact that on 70mph freeways in many states (e.g. California), the speed limit for vehicles towing trailers is 55mph. So if you're travelling at 55-60mph, you'll be trundling right along with the big rigs. My memories of long-haul drives between cities are of it being a constant exercise in passing slow trucks, so drivers are definitely on the lookout for slower traffic.

Comment: At that speed I would prefer the back highways rather than the interstates.

Comment: @ajd - note that slow semis are more easily seen than a Prius, and drivers are attuned to the semis and not so much to the slow car. Intentionally driving 15+ miles per hour under the posted speed limit is not a particularly safe thing to do, and will irritate many other drivers.

Comment: @JonCuster, I am not advocating for doing 15+ below the limit; my max under is at most 15mph under; e.g., I'd probably go 60mph if the limit is 75mph (which is the [max](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_the_United_States#/media/File:US_Speed_Limits_May_2015.svg) on this PHX-ABQ-AUS route), and hardly any roads have limits above 75mph in US (I may as well go 65mph if it's 80mph and road ain't empty).  BTW, I realised that going 50—60mph not only lets you conserve the fuel considerably, but also lets you enjoy the scenery without as much of a risk of a split second getting you off-road.

Comment: The posted speed limit is not what traffic flows at on either I40 or I10 - that is more like 80 out there. Now, the drive Phoenix to  Holbrook, or Phoenix to Socorro on back roads is quite beautiful and doesn’t have folks going 80 trying to tear-end you while they watch the scenery go by...

Comment: Long after the question was asked, but Phoenix to Socorroon US-60 would allow you to keep the speed down, but would end up costing a lot more in fuel due to the elevation changes.  Check out the Salt River Canyon on US-60.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single easy way to do this.  You will have to construct routes yourself, although websites like Google Maps are certainly going to be useful.  (You can use Street View to glean speed limits and pavement condition, for example, although not all areas are updated very often.  Some highways in nearby parts of Montana to me haven't been updated in Street View since 2008.)

However, I'd caution you to some degree against this approach as a blanket approach.  Certainly, sometimes, the secondary highways are perfectly pleasant to drive and quite safe.  However, it's always more dangerous to drive on undivided highways than on grade-separated divided highways (dual carriageways).

Another consideration is that if you drive significantly slower than the general flow of traffic, you'll actually be a hazard, creating bottlenecks.  This runs the risk of creating road rage, but even with other drivers being considerate, you're slowing their journey for your own benefit.

On the plus side, the secondary highways often have nice scenery in some parts of countries, and you have more ability to stop if you see something that's of interest for you (e.g. to take photographs).

You can go under the speed limits on controlled-access freeways and motorways, like the US Interstate highways, but unless traffic is light or road or weather conditions poor, I'd counsel against it.  On quiet divided highways, people can pass you easily, but on congested ones, again, you're causing a bottleneck.

You might be better to choose your moments when to drive in a relaxed fashion and when not to.

If fuel economy is your primary goal, bear in mind that there are other ways to improve fuel economy that will have fewer harmful effects on traffic flow (such as removing unnecessary weight from your vehicle, keeping the engine in prime operating order, maintaining the inflation of your tires, avoiding add-ons to your vehicle that change its aerodynamic profile, and accelerating and braking smoothly and carefully instead of abruptly or repeatedly).